# AzureDevOps - Different behavior from custom task for Services and Server

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I created a custom task using the documentation, however it works on Azure DevOps Services but on Server it gives the error

```
An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key
```

My first thoughts are "what is the parameter that is missing?" so i filled all the available and possible parameters and still continued with the error.

After that i went to the event viewer in the machine running Azure DevOps Server and got this error:

```
Detailed Message: The subscriber Pipelines Check Run: build completed event listener raised an exception while being notified of event Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.BuildCompletedEvent.
Exception Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: definition and repository (type ArgumentNullException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Pipelines.Server.Providers.TfsGitProvider.TfsGitConnectionCreator.IsProviderDefinition(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Pipelines.Server.Extensions.BuildCompletedEventListener2.HandleCompletedEvent(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IReadOnlyBuildData build, BuildDefinition definition)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Pipelines.Server.Extensions.BuildCompletedEventListener.ProcessEvent(IVssRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, Object notificationEvent, Int32& statusCode, String& statusMessage, ExceptionPropertyCollection& properties)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationEventService.SubscriptionList.Notify(IVssRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, Object notificationEventArgs, String& statusMessage, ExceptionPropertyCollection& properties, Exception& exception)
```

task.json:

```
{
    "id": "25156245-9317-48e2-bcf4-7dab4c130a3e",
    "name": "ping-pong-build-trigger",
    "friendlyName": "Ping Pong Build Trigger",
    "description": "Randomly trigger builds to find a sequenced build order",
    "helpMarkDown": "https://github.com/brunomartinspro/Ping-Pong-Build-Trigger-AzureDevOps",
    "category": "Build",
    "author": "Bruno Martins (brunomartins.pro)",
    "version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Patch": 0
    },
    "instanceNameFormat": "Ping Pong Build Trigger",
    "properties": {
        "mode": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Mode to be used",
            "label": "Mode",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "apiKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "label": "PAT",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "description": "Personal Access Token.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "source": {
            "type": "string",
            "label": "AzureDevOps Project URI",
            "defaultValue": "http://kamina.azuredevops.local/DefaultCollection/Kamina",
            "description": "AzureDevOps Project URI.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "projectName": {
            "type": "string",
            "label": "AzureDevOps Project Name",
            "defaultValue": "Kamina",
            "description": "AzureDevOps Project Name.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "sourceBranch": {
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Git Source Branch",
            "defaultValue": "develop",
            "description": "The branch the builds will trigger",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "lastKnownFile": {
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Sequence Location",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "description": "The location of the Build Order.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "maxErrorCycles": {
            "type": "int",
            "label": "Maximum Error Cycles",
            "defaultValue": 10,
            "description": "The number of fails allowed.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        "infiniteCycles": {
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Infinite Cycles",
            "defaultValue": "false",
            "description": "Infinite Cycles - only ends until everything succeeds.",
            "required": "true"
        }
    },
    "inputs": [{
            "name": "mode",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Mode",
            "defaultValue": "AzureDevOps",
            "helpMarkDown": "Mode to be used.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "apiKey",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "PAT",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "helpMarkDown": "Personal Access Token.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "source",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "AzureDevOps Project URI",
            "defaultValue": "http://kamina.azuredevops.local/DefaultCollection/Kamina",
            "helpMarkDown": "AzureDevOps Project URI.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "projectName",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "AzureDevOps Project Name",
            "defaultValue": "Kamina",
            "helpMarkDown": "AzureDevOps Project Name.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "sourceBranch",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Git Source Branch",
            "defaultValue": "develop",
            "helpMarkDown": "The branch the builds will trigger",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "lastKnownFile",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Sequence Location",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "helpMarkDown": "The location of the Build Order.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "maxErrorCycles",
            "type": "int",
            "label": "Maximum Error Cycles",
            "defaultValue": 10,
            "helpMarkDown": "The number of fails allowed.",
            "required": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "infiniteCycles",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Infinite Cycles",
            "defaultValue": "false",
            "helpMarkDown": "Infinite Cycles - only ends until everything succeeds.",
            "required": "true"
        }
    ],
    "execution": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "target": "ping-pong-build-trigger.ps1",
            "argumentFormat": ""
        }
    }
}
```

vss-extension.json

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "ping-pong-build-trigger-task",
    "name": "Ping Pong Build Trigger",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "publisher": "BrunoMartinsPro",
    "targets": [{
        "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }],
    "description": "Randomly trigger builds to find a sequenced build order",
    "categories": [
        "Azure Pipelines"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "extensionIcon.png"
    },
    "files": [{
        "path": "task"
    }],
    "contributions": [{
        "id": "ping-pong-build-trigger",
        "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "task"
        }
    }]
}
```

How can i use a custom task in both Services and Server?

The .vsix can be downloaded in the release page of the Github Repository: https://github.com/brunomartinspro/Ping-Pong-Build-Trigger-AzureDevOps

Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/715570/server-and-services-have-different-behavior.html

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that there is some sort of cache mechanism in the extensions, i need 3 azure devops server editions to debug.
The first one was used for development, the second one also for development but uninstalled and installed again, the third one for testing public releases.
I couldn't find the physical directory of where the cache gets stored, if there is cache at all.

Comment: Created https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/720080/azure-devops-extensions-have-cache.html